# synchronous UIWebview request

Tags: ios, uiwebview, synchronous

I'm currently working on a epub application.

So i use UIWebView in order to render my epub (html).
But, for animations reason, i would like to load my request synchronously.

How can i do it ?

I tried to use sendSynchronousRequest, but without success (my request were still asynchronous).
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem lays with the delay that `UIWebView` introduces when rendering the HTML, so that you do not want to show the user a blank page and only after a second or so the rendered page, the only way I have come up to deal with this is:

1. having initially the `UIWebView` hidden;
2. defining `webViewDidFinishLoad` so that when it fires the web view is made visible.

If you put your `UIWebView` into a contaning view and define its `alpha` properly, you can get nice transitions with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The only real difference in terms of user experience between synchronous and asynchronous is that in the former case the user interface freezes up. So if that is the effect you want, just set all the `userInteractionEnabled` properties to `NO` when you launch the request, and switch them back on once the request is finished in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can get the html as a string with this:

```
NSError * error;
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yoururl.com"];
NSString * htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

And the load the html:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:url];
```

Comment: That still not work. Most of the work is done synchronously, but not the [webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:url].